# creating a new sorted ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` as defined below:

```
public class ResourceList : ObservableCollection<Resource>
{
    public ResourceList() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class Resource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Resource()
    {
        Name = "";
        UserName = "";
        EMail = "";
        Date = "";
        Time = "";
        SWList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    ...
```

I would like to **sort** my instance of the above collection like so:

```
ResourceList = from resource in ResourceList
               orderby resource.Name descending
               select resource;
```

However this is not working! What am I doing wrong? Please explain properly as I am new to C# and MVVM-concept!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. But you need to update the bound collection itself and not change the collection reference.

A quick and dirty solution is:

```
ResourceList.Clear();
ResourceList.AddRange(from resource in ResourceList
               orderby resource.Name descending
               select resource);
```

where `AddRange` could be an extension method on `ObservableCollection<T>`, to actually add the IEnumerable to the collection, because (`ObservableCollection` doesn't not have an `AddRange()` akin to `List.AddRange()`). To help with the [AddRange](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx)

I think the second solution, but I'm not sure:  is to raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` event on the `ResourceList` property.

E.g.

```
class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public ObservableCollection<Resource> ResourceList{
    get{ return value; }
    set
    { 
      _resourceList = value ;
      OnPropertyChanged("ResourceList");
    } 

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I don't understand it though! Could you modify the class which I have provided so I can see how you implement `AddRange`?

Answer (score 0):

It is sorted, just send it to a list.

```
ResourceList = from resource in ResourceList
           orderby resource.Name descending
           select resource).ToList();
```

Comment: if `ResourceList` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, then this won't even compile.

Comment: Because Ienumerable uses deferred execution, at the time of interrogating the variable it wont show as sorted, once its 'cast' to a list you can see that it is sorted.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez if it is of type T, then it wont compile since you won't even know what Property in 'T' to sort by??

Comment: It's not about been deferred. `ObservableCollection<T>!=List<T>` (despite implementing `IEnumerable<T>`).. and also this is more about data binding than deferred execution.

Answer (score 0):

I know some of these fine users already posted valid solutions but i would also like to point out alternatives you can have.

1) First of all of if there is no need for you to sort `ResourceList` you could do it directly within your View itself. Here is a rough example applied to your context:

```
// Add this at the top
// xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ResourceListViewSource"
                          Source="{Binding ResourceList}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="{Binding Name}"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Note that you need to add a namespace to ComponentModel and a reference to WindowsBase dll.
Then use it like so:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceListViewSource}}"
```

2) If you still want to use LINQ, approach suggested by Lews Therin would do (make an extension method), but for example simply assigning it would work:

```
ResourceList = new ObservableCollection<Resource>(from resource in ResourceList orderby resource.Name descending select resource);
```

since the constructor can take it. Note that you need to manually call `PropertyChanged` event on your `ObservableCollection` (within `set` would be the best place or at least straight after the sorting logic) in this case or else your View will not get notified of the changes.

Here is the handler code you will need for the PropertyChanged event:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
    if (propertyChanged != null)
        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

At the end of the day you can always output the sorted list into an implicitly typed local variable and take it from there.

Hope this helps.

P.S. If you still want to know how to make a sorting extension method to `ObservableCollection` let me know, i can provide some example for that.